# Using multiple await in map

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I am a little bit confused about the code below.

```
 let bookingID
 result = await Promise.all(result.map(async (item) => {
      bookingID = item.id;
      console.log('###############################');
      AData = await book.fetchA(bookingID);
      console.log(bookingID);
      BData = await book.fetchB(bookingID);
      console.log('==============================');

      return {
        'AData ': AData ,
        'BData ': BData ,
        'id': bookingID
      };
  }));
```

What I get in console is: (NOTE. the id is the same. Always be the last one)

```
###############################
###############################
2918849262429175808
2918849262429175808
==============================
==============================
```

It seems that something is wrong with the loop logic, the output should have been

```
###############################
2918849262429175807
==============================
###############################
2918849262429175808
==============================
```

But if I change the sequence of console.log to

```
      console.log('###############################');
      console.log(bookingID);
      AData = await book.fetchA(bookingID);
      BData = await book.fetchB(bookingID);
      console.log('==============================');
```

the output is (NOTE. the id is different)

```
###############################
2918849262429175807
###############################
2918849262429175808
==============================
==============================
```

I am totally confused. 8-（

Just find a interesting thing. When I use console.log(item.id) instead of console.log(bookingID), it could get the right id result.
What is going on with 'bookingID = item.id'? Why it always gets the same id when console.log(bookingID) is after AData = await book.fetchA(bookingID)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Node.js is single threaded `Promise.all` doesn't block if one the `Promise` awaits for result so when first promise awaits for  `AData = await book.fetchA(bookingID);` another promise continues calls to `console.log` and awaits again so end result is

```
###############################
###############################
2918849262429175808
2918849262429175808
==============================
==============================
```

Similar argument can be made for second case. Only the order of returned value is preserved on call to `Promise.all`

Comment: But why it always gets the same id when console.log(bookingID) is after AData = await book.fetchA(bookingID)? It should get different id at least.

Comment: because loop is taking reference from `let bookingID` declared globally in first case so after awaiting on  `await book.fetchA(bookingID);` its value becomes `2918849262429175808` in both promises.

Comment: Still not clear, sorry.  When in the first loop,  bookingID = item.id; bookID is 1 for example. then await book.fetchA(bookingID), right? And then, the value '1' of bookID should be sent to next await, book.fetchB(bookingID); at least. But the await book.fetchB(bookingID); always get the last bookID 2.

Comment: I got it! thank you Gaurav Dhiman! Yes, the bookingID declared globally, it should not be like that. It should declare in the loop.